# Memory Error in processing Python Code for Project Euler problem

Tags: python, function, loops, error-handling

Tried Running a code to solve an archived Project Euler Problem

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3
> or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

but I am now getting something called a memory error. Am I doing something wrong? Pl. Explain. My Code-

```
def euler_1(n):
    x=0
    abc=[]
    while x<n:
        if x%3==0 or x%5==0:
            abc.append(x)
            x+=1
        else:
            pass

    return sum(abc)
```

Comment: can you add the actual error you are receiving?

Comment: If you step through this code with a debugger, do you notice anything odd about the value of `x` as the program iterates through the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you increment your counter each time you iterate over the loop. Otherwise you'll get stuck on a non-multiple and encounter an infinite loop.

Consider the following case. When `x=4`:

```
if x%3==0 or x%5==0:
# evaluates to false
```

So we move the `else` statement and go back to the top of the loop. Nothing has changed, so x is still 4, and the process repeats infinitely. If you are set on using a while loop, you need to move `x+=1` outside the ifs to happen in all cases:

```
def euler_1(n):
    x=0
    abc=[]
    while x<n:
        if x%3==0 or x%5==0:
            abc.append(x)
        x+=1
    return sum(abc)
```

However, if I could make a couple recommendations: First, you don't need to start your counter at 0, but at your smallest integer for which you want to find multiples. There is no sense iteration over 0, 1, and 2, since they won't ever count.

Secondly, I would recommend using either a for loop or a list comprehension, since these will take care of incrementing the counter with each loop, regardless of outcome. Make sure you set the end of the range to `n+1` since Python ranges are half-open sets, i.e. do not include the last number.

```
abc = sum([x for x in range(0, n+1) if x%3==0 or x%5==0)]
```

or

```
abc=0
for x in range(0, n+1):
    if x%3==0 or x%5==0:
        abc += x
return abc
```

Comment: could you explain why x+=1 has to be moved outside though?

Comment: @DrDexterMorganMD sorry, just saw this. It has to be moved outside the `if` statement because you want to increase `i` **every time** you go through the loop, **not just** when if `if` statement is `True` (i.e. the number is a multiple). Otherwise the **only time** `i` increases is when it's a multiple; when not a multiple, `i` never increases, and so you get stuck on the same number in perpetuity.

Answer (score 1):

Just use list comprehension and skip the while-loop and the append which just slows things down.

```
sum([x for x in range(1, 1000) if x%3==0 or x%5==0]) # -> 233168
```

Comment: I think the OP doesn't want an optimal solution for his problem but why it doesn't work.

Comment: You can even skip the list building - just generator exp. on this:  `sum(x for x in range(1, 1000) if x%3 ==0 or x%5 ==0)`

Answer (score 1):

In the else statement, delete the `pass` statement and write `x+=1` because updating x is independent of the condition. If you don't update x if condition is not satisfied then condition will remain unsatisfied forever and the loop will keep going